# z-index not working in Angular UI Datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Fn2S0fKOwnLHjeWHHP3?p=preview) I have an Angular UI Datepicker inside a div (the div has orange background). The problem is that the Datepicker is truncated, even though I set `z-index: 99999`. If I remove from the div `overflow-y:auto` the Datepicker is shown, however I need the div to scroll when there's an overflow. How to fix this problem?

HTML:

```
<div style="height:200px;padding:30px;background-color:orange;overflow-y:auto">
  <p class="input-group" style="z-index:99999">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dt" is-open="config.opened"
          uib-datepicker-popup popup-placement="top-left" datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
           ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.opened = false;

    $scope.dateOptions = {
       showWeeks: false
    };

    $scope.open1 = function(){
        $scope.opened = true;
      };


});

app.directive('dir2', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',          
        scope: {
          someVar: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'dir2.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 

           scope.config = {};
           scope.config.opened = true;

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very common case with `tooltip`, `datepicker` or `popover` in such cases it is better choice to append the content to `body` so the current element styling doesn't matter. Basically in this case you could append datepicker to body by setting below `datepikcer-append-to-body` to `true`.

```
datepicker-append-to-body="true"
```

Don't go for setting `z-index`, it may work by tweaking few things, but it could unintentionally break other piece of software.

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XGcewZAnVPc97zZIbg2H?p=preview)